# Essential tools for a Distributed development team

Tags: version-control, distributed

I want to setup a website where a team of developers (distributed all over the world) can get together and develop Software.

So far (after a ton of reading) im coming close to the conclusion that the tools I will need are: a Version control system (git , mercurial), a bugtracker and and project manager? This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365016/distributed-development-team-tools-needed) also help come to this conclusion.

Now my questions are:
- Am I correct and what other tools will I need?
- Will is be possible to integrate these tools with my website?
by this I mean the look ( my website logo) and feel (not having to bounce around from one link to another)?
- I would also prefer hosting my own git/mercurial repo as i dont want to have to go open source is is this advised?
-Free/open source applications would be best

Also another question, I had a look at redmine, does this cover all the things that i would need? as i see it has a lot of features..

Answer (score 0):

You want to reinvent the wheel... do you know it?!

You forgot at least:

- Future planning (and bugtracker will become issuetracker)
- Team communication (realtime and|or non-realtime)
- Some type of *internal documentation* (wiki?)
- Code reviews
- Unit-tests, build and deploy tools

Maybe private repository on code-hosting sites will be more natural (and fast) way? Or you can try GitHub Enterprise or Assembla Private Installation